# Regex match till the first number occurs in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

**`given text = "ABC123XYZ"`**

How to extract `ABC` out of the text in python using `regex`?

Guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: it would be better if you could add more description about what exactly is required here. Are you looking for `ABC` which is always at the beginning/in-between of `text`? Or are you searching for first three alphabets of `text`? also preferably some more examples of `text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]*", "ABC123XYZ").group()
'ABC'
```

Or use `re.IGNORECASE`-flag for a cleaner definition.

```
>>> re.search(r"[a-z]*", a, re.IGNORECASE).group()
'ABC'
```

Comment: This will not work for `'?d-fe..34'`

Comment: That's true, however the op was not very specific on the details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions, or [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = r'(.*?)\d+.*?$'
>>> re.findall(exp, 'dafadfader343dvdfdfd3343fdfd')
['dafadfader']
```

Depending on what you know about the text, this is an alternate solution:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), 'adfdafdaf343afdadffad'))
'adfdafdaf'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the leters ABC in many ways using regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "ABC123XYZ"
```

Using negation(NOT character class),

```
>>> re.search(r'^[^\d]*', str)
>>> m.group()
'ABC'
```

Using lookahead

```
>>> m = re.search(r'^.*(?=123)', str)
>>> m.group()
'ABC'

>>> m = re.search(r'^.*(?=\d{3})', str)
>>> m.group()
'ABC'
```

Using lookbehind,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=^)[A-Z]*', str)
>>> m.group()
'ABC'
```

Using Character class

```
>>> m = re.search(r'^[A-Z]*', str)
>>> m.group()
'ABC'
```